# display text parameters explanation

Tags: python, pygame

```
def texts(score):
  font=pygame.font.Font(None,30)
  scoretext=font.render("Score:"+str(score), 1,(255,255,255))
  screen.blit(scoretext, (500, 457))
```

what this second parameter(`1`) in `font.render` is for?

```
class safeguardClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image_file, location = [0,0]):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #call Sprite initializer
       self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
```

Moreover,kindly guide me what is `self` in above subclass?

Comment: Whenever you are not sure about the parameters, and what existing library functions do, starting with documentation of the same is a very good start. If you choose not to see the documentation, it would take ages to understand what-the-Jesus is the code all about? It won't make more sense than random typing on the keyboard. Documentation for the Pygame render function is here - http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is anti-aliasing, per the [PyGame documentation.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render)

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) of `pygame.font.Font.render` it shows:

> ```
> render(text, antialias, color, background=None) -> Surface
> ```
>
> This creates a new Surface with the specified text rendered on it. Pygame provides no way to directly draw text on an existing Surface: instead you must use Font.render() to create an image (Surface) of the text, then blit this image onto another Surface.
>
> (...)
>
> The `antialias` argument is a **boolean**: **if true** the **characters will have smooth edges**.

Furthermore `self` is a reference to the object you are constructing in the [`__init__` function](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-init.html).